How to sort text values the same way as a web-based staircase generator
I'm trying to sort some text values in the same way as you can with this web-based staircase generator (https://authoredup.com/tools/text-staircase).

Here are my values in A2:A21:








Bhutan


The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland


South Africa


The Republic of the Marshall Islands


Netherlands


Central African Republic


Dominica


The Democratic Republic of the Congo


Peru


Papua New Guinea


Jamaica


Antigua and Barbuda


El Salvador


Bosnia and Herzegovina


Japan


The Democratic Republic of São Tomé and Príncipe


Nicaragua


The Federated States of Micronesia


Bangladesh


The Independent and Sovereign Republic of Kiribati



There are four variations, and I've managed to do the two easier ones. For short to long, the formula in B2 is =SORTBY(A2:A21,LEN(A2:A21)), and for long to short in C2, it's =SORTBY(A2:A21,LEN(A2:A21),-1).
However, I'm struggling to come up with formulas for the pyramid and chevron styles (I've included the values in the screenshot to show what should be returned).
What can I do?

Sort the list twice.  The first time, sort it by length, as you are already doing.
The second time, sort it by a function of its position in the length-sorted list (you can use the SEQUENCE function here), for example -2^[Position]



Position
-2^[Position]
¦
Sorted Position
Sorted -2^[Position]




1
-2
¦
5
-32


2
4
¦
3
-8


3
-8
¦
1
-2


4
16
¦
2
4


5
-32
¦
4
16



This will move the first item from the first sorted list to the middle of the second sorted list, and alternate the subsequent items before or after it.
=SORTBY(SORTBY(A2:A21,LEN(A2:A21), 1), -2^SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A21)), 1)

To swap between "Pyramid" and "Chevron", swap the order of the first sort — this will determine if the middle value is the shortest or the longest.

To simplify things somewhat, you can also use the LET function to define the range once per function:
#Short to Long
=LET(_list, A2:A21, SORTBY(_list, LEN(_list), 1))

#Long to Short
=LET(_list, A2:A21, SORTBY(_list, LEN(_list), -1))

#Pyramid
=LET(_list, A2:A21, SORTBY(SORTBY(_list, LEN(_list), -1), -2^SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_list)), 1))

#Chevron
=LET(_list, A2:A21, SORTBY(SORTBY(_list, LEN(_list), 1), -2^SEQUENCE(COUNTA(_list)), 1))


You can use these formulas:
E1
=LET(data,A1:A20,
sortData,SORTBY(data,LEN(data)),
upperPart,INDEX(sortData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sortData)/2,,1,2)),
lowerPart,INDEX(sortData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sortData)/2,,2,2)),
VSTACK(SORTBY(upperPart,LEN(upperPart),-1),lowerPart))

and
G1
=LET(data,A1:A20,
sortData,SORTBY(data,LEN(data)),
upperPart,INDEX(sortData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sortData)/2,,1,2)),
lowerPart,INDEX(sortData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sortData)/2,,2,2)),
VSTACK(upperPart,SORTBY(lowerPart,LEN(lowerPart),-1)))



Thanks for the fun task!
=LET(
    stairs, A1:A20,
    odd_indices, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(stairs) / 2, , 1, 2),
    short_to_long, SORTBY(stairs, LEN(stairs)),
    pyramid, VSTACK(odd_indices, SORT(odd_indices + 1, , -1)),
    chevron, VSTACK(SORT(odd_indices + 1, , -1), odd_indices),
    INDEX(short_to_long, CHOOSE({1, 2}, pyramid, chevron))
)


